# How to partition a graph, so as the weight of the nodes in each partition would be between two numbers?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, operations-research

There is a specific problem in operations research that is converted into a graph:

I would like to partition the graph into *n* sub-graphs, so as the nodes in sub-graphs are connected, and the sum of the weights of the nodes is between two numbers, *a* and *b*.

Since I'm coming from an operations research background, I first thought about proposing a MIP model in order to solve the problem, but soon there were a lot of problems on how to model the constraints. I understand the usual edge-cut algorithms and have used them to tackle the problem.

I'll describe my thought process until now, hoping you have any ideas on this problem:

I generate a spanning tree, then I pick up some *n* edges, so the number of the partitions would be fine, from now on I need to add or delete nodes from each partition to reach a feasible response. At this stage, I feel like there should be a logical process. I tried to describe a procedure on paper, but couldn't get it right.

I wish also to know if the problem of partitioning the graph into *n* subgraphs with weights between *a* and *b*, could be feasible, given a special graph.

Comment: Is the graph a tree, are the constraints on nodes or how the graph is built?

Comment: @Lecagy thanks for your attention. The main problem is a graph, not a tree, you can see a sample graph in this link pasteboard.co/IKVhKom.png. the constraint is that the sum of the nodes in each partition needs to be between numbers a and b and they should be connected.